# Running a JAX-WS web service in development or production mode

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a web service generated with `wsimport` (in an ANT task) for which I want to handle the `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException` exception that appears when I'm sending an invalid XML request.

In order to throw this exception I just send an unbalanced tag to the server and I get back:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag &lt;/m:BAR>; expected &lt;/m:BR>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [16,38]]</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Unfortunately in my code I see no way of catching this exception and sending back a standard message, instead of automatically sending some webservice-internal exception that the client might not be able to parse.

Is there a way to tell JAX-Ws to run in **production** or in **development** mode? Where in **production** mode it would allow me to override the message being sent in reply to an erroneous request?

Or at least implement some kind of hook that will call a method of mine when an exception happens in JAX-WS's code...

I am running the service on Glassfish 4.1.2.

My ANT script for building the webservice from the `wsdl` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project name="WSDL to Java generator" default="wsimport">  
    <path id="wsimport.classpath">
        <fileset dir="../../EAR/EarContent/lib">
            <include name="commons-beanutils-*.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-lang-*.jar"/>
            <include name="commons-logging-*.jar"/>
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="../../Common/ant-libs">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport" classpathref="wsimport.classpath"/>

    <target name="wsimport">
        <wsimport verbose="true" wsdl="../schemas/WebService.wsdl"  wsdlLocation="../schemas/WebService.wsdl" binding="./ws-build-bindings.xjb">
            <xjcarg line="-Xannotate"/>
            <xjcarg line="-Xinheritance"/>

            <arg line="-keep"/>
            <arg line="-d ../src"/>
            <arg line="-p org.company.name.message"/>

            <arg line="-Xnocompile"/>    
        </wsimport>
    </target>
</project>
```

The generated interface looks like this:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.3.0
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "WebService", targetNamespace = "http://company.com/foo/WebService/")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface WebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "PublishEvent", action = "PublishEvent")
    @WebResult(name = "ResponseMessage", targetNamespace = "http://foo.bar/schema/message", partName = "response")
    public ResponseMessageType publishEvent(
        @WebParam(name = "EventMessage", targetNamespace = "http://foo.bar/schema/message", partName = "event")
        EventMessageType event);

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Request", action = "Request")
    @WebResult(name = "ResponseMessage", targetNamespace = "http://foo.bar/schema/message", partName = "response")
    public ResponseMessageType request(
        @WebParam(name = "RequestMessage", targetNamespace = "http://foo.bar/schema/message", partName = "request")
        RequestMessageType request);

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Response", action = "Response")
    public void response(
        @WebParam(name = "ResponseMessage", targetNamespace = "http://foo.bar/schema/message", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, partName = "response")
        Holder<ResponseMessageType> response);

}
```

The generated class extending `Service`:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;    
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.3.0
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "WebService", targetNamespace = "http://company.com/foo/WebService/", wsdlLocation = "../schemas/WebService.wsdl")
public class WebService_Service
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL WebSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException WebSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName WebSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://company.com/foo/WebService/", "WebService");

    static {
        WebSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = org.company.name.message.WebService_Service.class.getResource("../schemas/WebService.wsdl");
        WebServiceException e = null;
        if (WebSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION == null) {
            e = new WebServiceException("Cannot find '../schemas/WebService.wsdl' wsdl. Place the resource correctly in the classpath.");
        }
        WebSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public WebService_Service() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), WebSERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public WebService_Service(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), WebSERVICE_QNAME, features);
    }

    public WebService_Service(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WebSERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public WebService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WebSERVICE_QNAME, features);
    }

    public WebService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public WebService_Service(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "WebServiceSOAP")
    public WebService getWebServiceSOAP() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://company.com/foo/WebService/", "WebServiceSOAP"), WebService.class);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "WebServiceSOAP")
    public WebService getWebServiceSOAP(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://company.com/foo/WebService/", "WebServiceSOAP"), WebService.class, features);
    }

    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (WebSERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw WebSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return WebSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }

}
```

And here's my implementation of the interface (with the code doing the actual work omitted), when an invalid request is made, there's no way for me to catch it since my methods below are not called:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;

import org.company.name.message.ErrorType.ErrorLevelEnum;
import org.company.name.message.EventMessageType;
import org.company.name.message.HeaderType;
import org.company.name.message.WebService;
import org.company.name.message.RequestMessageType;
import org.company.name.message.ResponseMessageType;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.company.name.message.WebService")
public class Web implements WebService {
    @Override
    public ResponseMessageType publishEvent(EventMessageType event) {
        ResponseMessageBuilder responseBuilder = new ResponseMessageBuilder();
        try
        {
            // build response here

        }
        catch (WebException exception) {
            // error building response
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // general error
        }

        return responseBuilder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseMessageType request(RequestMessageType request) {
        ResponseMessageBuilder responseBuilder = new ResponseMessageBuilder();

        try
        {
            // build response here

        }
        catch (WebException exception) {
            // error building response
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // general error
        }

        return responseBuilder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public void response(Holder<ResponseMessageType> response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by using a `SOAPHandler` (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-soaphandlers.htm#WSGET3446).

The handler intercepts the request, tries to `unmarshal` it (via JAXB) and if an exception is thrown, I customize the response message (ie. fully replace it by doing `messageContext.setMessage(soapFaultMessage);` in the `handleMessage` method of your`SOAPHandler`) and send it back (by returning `false` from the `handleMessage` method.

Also, it's worth looking into the `SOAPFaultException` class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException.html) which you can throw and the soap fault response message is customized to your liking.